# Kак cделать функционал по типу:

Tags: python

мне нужно добавить возможность добавления студента в список, удаление студента из списка, и вывод информации о студенте по введенным в консоль фамилией.**как зделать функционал по типу: 1 - добавить студента, 2 - удалить студента
3 - вывод информации о студенте** ;
мне нужно сделать функционал который содержит следующие функции 1) добавления студента в список 2) удаление студента 3) вывод информации о студенте и после нажатия например цифры 2 у нас спрашивается фамилия студента которого мы хотим удалить и после введения фамилии студент должен быть удален из списка и выводиться новый список без этого студента

```
student_list = []
my_string = "Гринер Ирина Андреевна; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Иванов Михаил Владимирович; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Петлевая Софья Александровна; 18 лет студент 1 курса;"

#Добавление нового студента (записи) в список студентов.
def get_student(s, student_list):
    s = s.replace(';', "")
    list_of_student_temp = s.split(" ") #список, в котором храним новых студентов
    
    while(len(list_of_student_temp) != 0):
        about_student = []
        about_student.append(list_of_student_temp[0:3]) # ФИО
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[3:4][0])) #Возраст
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[6:7][0])) # Курc
        student_list.append(about_student)
        list_of_student_temp = list_of_student_temp[8:]
    return student_list      

#Удаление студента из списка студентов.(по ФИО, возрасту и курсу)

def delete_student(student_list, name, age, course):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if(" ".join(student_list[i][0]) == name and student_list[i][1] == age and course == student_list[i][2]):
            student_list.pop(i);
            return student_list
    print("Такого студента не существует!")

#Вывод информации о студенте
def show_by_surname(student_list, surname):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if(student_list[i][0][0] == surname):
            print("ФИО: ", " ".join(student_list[i][0]), "| Возраст: ", student_list[i][1], "| Курс:", student_list[i][2])
```

Comment: Отредактирйте, пожалуйста, заголовок так, чтобы он отражал суть вопроса. Спасибо!

Comment: А вообще, попробуйте делать slit не по пробелу, а по "; ". Тогда вы получите массив, на нечетных позициях которого лежат ФИО студентов, а на четных -- возраст и курс. Это намного упростит ваш код и сделает его более читабельным.

И если я верно понял ваш вопрос, то вам нужно просто создать бесконечный цикл, в котором проверять: если пользователь ввел 1, писать ему "введите фио и возраст студента", принимать данные и вызывать соответсвующую функцию. Аналогично можно поступить с другими командами

Comment: мне нужно сделать функционал который содержит следующие функции 1) добавления студента в список 2) удаление студента 3) вывод информации о студенте и после нажатия например цифры 2 у нас спрашивается фамилия студента которого мы хотим удалить и после введения фамилии студент должен быть удален из списка и выводиться новый список без этого студента

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```
student_list = []
            
while True:
    action = input("\nВведите действие: 1 - add, 2 - del, 3 - show, Enter - выход ")
    if not action: 
        print(* student_list, sep='\n')
        break
    elif action == '1': 
        pass
        full_name = input("Введите ФИО: ")
        age = input("Введите возраст: ")
        course = input("Введите курс: ") 
        if full_name in [ st[0] for st in student_list]:
            print("Такой студент уже существует!")
        else:
            student_list.append([full_name, age, course])
    elif action == '2': 
        full_name = input("Введите ФИО: ")
        if not full_name in [ st[0] for st in student_list]:
            print("Такого студента не существует!")
        else:
            index = [ i for i, st in enumerate(student_list) if st[0]==full_name][0]
            student_list.pop(index)
        
    elif action == '3': 
        full_name = input("Введите ФИО: ")
        if not full_name in [ st[0] for st in student_list]:
            print("Такого студента не существует!")
        else:
            st = [ st for st in student_list if st[0]==full_name][0]
            print(f"ФИО: {st[0]} | Возраст: {st[1]} | Курс: {st[2]}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> а как сделать так чтобы список был сначала не пустой?

```
student_list = [
    ['Oxu62133 Hello World', '18', '1'],
    ['Иванов Иван Иванович', '21', '3'],
]
...
```

Comment: а как сделать так чтобы список был сначала не пустой?

Comment: @oxu62133 смотрите обновление

Comment: @oxu62133 вставьте в конце этих действий `print(* student_list, sep='\n')`, ну или как вы там хотите выводить список

Comment: а как зделать чтобы после выполнения каждой из функций спрашивайте у пользователя «Вы хотите
Далее?" Если ответ «да», то снова выводите меню. если
ответ «нет», то завершаете выполнения программы.

Comment: @oxu62133 я же сделал `Enter - выход` - зачем вам что-то еще. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: да спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
# coding:utf8
import argparse

student_list = []
my_string = "Гринер Ирина Андреевна; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Иванов Михаил Владимирович; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Петлевая Софья Александровна; 18 лет студент 1 курса;"


# Добавление нового студента (записи) в список студентов.
def get_student(s, student_list):
    s = s.replace(';', "")
    list_of_student_temp = s.split(" ")  # список, в котором храним новых студентов

    while len(list_of_student_temp) != 0:
        about_student = []
        about_student.append(list_of_student_temp[0:3])  # ФИО
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[3:4][0]))  # Возраст
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[6:7][0]))  # Курc
        student_list.append(about_student)
        list_of_student_temp = list_of_student_temp[8:]
    return student_list


# Удаление студента из списка студентов.(по ФИО, возрасту и курсу)

def delete_student(student_list, name, age, course):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if (" ".join(student_list[i][0]) == name and student_list[i][1] == age and course == student_list[i][2]):
            student_list.pop(i)
            return student_list
    print("Такого студента не существует!")


# Вывод информации о студенте
def show_by_surname(student_list, surname):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if (student_list[i][0][0] == surname):
            print("ФИО: ", " ".join(student_list[i][0]), "| Возраст: ", student_list[i][1], "| Курс:",
                  student_list[i][2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_student(my_string, student_list)
    func_choice = input('1) добавления студента в список 2) удаление студента 3) вывод информации о студенте')
    if func_choice == '1':
        choice = input(
            'Добавления студента в список. Введите ФИО Возраст Курс. Пример -  Гринер Ирина Андреевна; 18 лет Студент 1 курса;')
        print(get_student(choice, student_list))
    elif func_choice == '2':
        choice = input('Удаление студента. Введите ФИО Возраст Курс. Пример - Гринер Ирина Андреевна 18 1').split()
        print(choice)
        name = choice[0] + ' ' + choice[1] + ' ' + choice[2]
        print(name)
        age = int(choice[3])
        course = int(choice[4])
        print(delete_student(student_list, name, age, course))
    elif func_choice == '3':
        choice = input('Вывод информации о студенте. Пример - Гринер')
        show_by_surname(student_list, choice)
```

Тут без параметров и всего прочего просто запускаете модуль и
жмете соответствующие кнопки:1) добавления студента в список 2) удаление студента 3) вывод информации о студенте

Answer (score -1):

```
# coding:utf8
import argparse

student_list = []
my_string = "Гринер Ирина Андреевна; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Иванов Михаил Владимирович; 18 лет Студент 1 курса; Петлевая Софья Александровна; 18 лет студент 1 курса;"


# Добавление нового студента (записи) в список студентов.
def get_student(s, student_list):
    s = s.replace(';', "")
    list_of_student_temp = s.split(" ")  # список, в котором храним новых студентов

    while len(list_of_student_temp) != 0:
        about_student = []
        about_student.append(list_of_student_temp[0:3])  # ФИО
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[3:4][0]))  # Возраст
        about_student.append(int(list_of_student_temp[6:7][0]))  # Курc
        student_list.append(about_student)
        list_of_student_temp = list_of_student_temp[8:]
    return student_list


# Удаление студента из списка студентов.(по ФИО, возрасту и курсу)

def delete_student(student_list, name, age, course):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if (" ".join(student_list[i][0]) == name and student_list[i][1] == age and course == student_list[i][2]):
            student_list.pop(i)
            return student_list
    print("Такого студента не существует!")


# Вывод информации о студенте
def show_by_surname(student_list, surname):
    for i in range(len(student_list)):
        if (student_list[i][0][0] == surname):
            print("ФИО: ", " ".join(student_list[i][0]), "| Возраст: ", student_list[i][1], "| Курс:",
                  student_list[i][2])


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Student base')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--added', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help='Добавление нового студента (записи) в список студентов.')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--deleted', nargs='+', type=str,
                    help='Удаление студента из списка студентов.(по ФИО, возрасту и курсу)', )
parser.add_argument('-v', '--view', type=str, help='Вывод информации о студенте', )
parser.add_argument('-y', '--year', type=int, help='Возраст', )
parser.add_argument('-c', '--course', type=int, help='Курс', )
args = parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_student(my_string,student_list)
    # print(delete_student(student_list, 'Гринер Ирина Андреевна', 18, 1))
    # print(args)
    if args.added:
        end_list = ' '.join(args.added)
        print(get_student(end_list, student_list))
    elif args.deleted:
        name = ' '.join(args.deleted)
        age= args.year
        course = args.course
        # print(name,age,course)
        # print(student_list)
        print(delete_student(student_list,name,age,course))
    elif args.view:
        print(show_by_surname(student_list, args.view))

    # print(delete_student(student_list,'Гринер Ирина Андреевна', 18, 1))
```

чтобы показать инфо о студенте вводите в консоль название {ваше название модуля}.py - Например

Показать инфо о студенте - `probe.py -v Гринер`

Добавить студента - `probe.py -a Гринер Ирина Андреевна; 18 лет Студент 1 курса;`

Удалить студента - `probe.py -d Гринер Ирина Андреевна -y 18 -c 1`

Показать инфо о студенте: параметр `-v` принимает только фамилию студента

Добавить студента : параметр `-a` принимает строку

Удалить студента:  параметр  `-d` принимает  ФИО `-y` - возраст `-с` - курс

Удаление принимает три параметра не забудьте, остальные по одному параметру.
Их необходимо указывать как в примере.

Comment: мне нужно сделать функционал который содержит следующие функции 1) добавления студента в список 2) удаление студента 3) вывод информации о студенте и после нажатия например цифры 2 у нас спрашивается фамилия студента которого мы хотим удалить и после введения фамилии студент должен быть удален из списка и выводиться новый список без этого студента